# JQuery HideAllShowOne + Link to open DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this JQuery only using HideAllShowOne:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
function HideContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
function HideAllShowOne(d) {
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
function HideAllShowOne(d) {
// Between the quotation marks, list the id values of each div.

var IDvaluesOfEachDiv = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14";

//-------------------------------------------------------------
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/[,\s"']/g," ");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/^\s*/,"");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/\s*$/,"");
IDvaluesOfEachDiv = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.replace(/  +/g," ");
var IDlist = IDvaluesOfEachDiv.split(" ");
for(var i=0; i<IDlist.length; i++) { HideContent(IDlist[i]); }
ShowContent(d);
}
//--></script>
```

With this HTML

```
<div class="heading marg_none">
    <h5><a href="javascript:HideAllShowOne('2')">Step 2. Adding Services</a></h5>
</div>
<div id="2" style="display: none;">         
     <p>
         Watch the video for full details.            
     </p>
</div>
```

This works fine for opening each section in a FAQ style page on my website but what I want be able to link to each question from somewhere else on the site and have it automatically scroll to that DIV and open it. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: so you want to click a link to take you to a new page and have it scroll down to a certain section on load?

Answer (score 0):

The url must be like: http://www.aaa.com/faq#1 (For 1st question) Hash shows that is 1st question. You can check is there any hash on URL below this code:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Has exist
} else {
  // Hash doesn't exist
}
```

Then you should get hash from URL below this code:

```
var url = "http://www.aaa.com/faq#1";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
```

This hash should be "1" in this example. And final step is scrolling to div:

```
window.location.hash = hash;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that worked. Although I may be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: If you redirect to hashed url from out of page the examples should work